# Analog of Java substring() and lastIndexOf() on Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

In java, this code worked:

```
String tempDir = c.getString(0);
tempDir = tempDir.substring(0, tempDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

But I can't write this code in kotlin:

```
var string: String = c.getString(0)
var sequence: CharSequence = tempDir.subSequence(0, string.length)
var indexLast = sequence.lastIndexOf("/",0,false) // error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val tempDir = c.getString(0).substringBeforeLast("/")
```

Comment: this is the correct answer